# Are there any alternatives to quitting?

Tags: management, united-states, working-conditions

In some ways this company is great, but in other ways it's not so great. There are several rules that the owner creates out of thin air that he will not cave on.

Recently, our A/C broke in the office. Most of the day is manageable, but the last two-three hours are unbearable. It's an on A/C system so it will need completely replaced, which we were told could be months. My boss's suggestion was to move people to the only room that is cooled in the building. This is a huge hassle. We'll need to move the phones in there and reroute the lines, along with all of our computer equipment.

He said he was open to suggestions, but when I brought up wearing more casual clothes, he said "we'll see how hot it gets". I know him well and that means "no". Our dress code is dress pants, collared shirt, etc unless we're in the field that day. If we're in the field, we're allowed to wear t shirts. The owner is very strict on this dress code too. People that were going into the field that day were immediately questioned about their attire (t-shirts) as soon as the owner saw them.

Another thing that irritates me a bit about working here is how the owner treats PTO. On a couple of occasions I've heard him vent to our HR lady about how he can't believe people are taking certain amounts of sick time, which is allocated to them. Then in return I've heard the HR lady vent to a couple people about how the boss doesn't understand. She made a good point in my opinion, which is that he can take time off anytime and have it paid. He has said that he has never took a sick day since he started the company, but that's not exactly true because he just doesn't count them.

Is there any possible way to improve the situation before quitting?

Answer (score 7):

**Culture trickles down.**

I've seen this from the good side, and from the bad side, and I'm pretty convinced it's universal.  So what your question is isn't "Is there any possible way to improve the situation before quitting?"  It's "What degree of change can I bring about with the CEO?"  Because, realistically, you're not changing the situation unless you change the CEO's outlook.

... and I gotta say, that's a pretty tall order.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any possible way to improve the situation before quitting?

Personally, I think it's a bit of an overreaction to consider quitting, just to the fact that your boss is strict regarding dress code and for complaining about people taking PTO (which is different from denying the PTO).

However, if *you* feel that such facts make it a place you no longer want to work for then it is up to you, but I suggest you don't decide that so lightly.

> He said he was open to suggestions, but when I brought up wearing more casual clothes, he said "we'll see how hot it gets". I know him well and that means "no".

You may know him well but it is not for sure that his answer will be negative, even more given the fact this is an extraordinary situation.

Until you get a clear answer you can't tell for sure your idea has been dismissed. Feel free to politely remind your boss if he considered the feasibility of your alternative, as well as trying to think of other alternatives (opening the windows? etc.).

> Another thing that irritates me a bit about working here is how the owner treats PTO. On a couple of occasions I've heard him vent to our HR lady about how he can't believe people are taking certain amounts of sick time, which is allocated to them.

It's irritating, I get it, but does it prevent you from doing your work? I would doubt that.

Besides, you sate that your boss is just complaining about some PTO. He is not actually denying or removing the PTO (which would be quite different). I doubt there is a "perfect" boss, and each one most surely have at least one fault or thing that irritates you, but this you mention seems something that doesn't really affect you besides being a bit annoying.

Again, if these facts are *really* negative to you and they don't seem to change or improve then consider finding a job, landing an offer, and giving your notice. Just make sure that is something you are willing to do.

Comment: One thing to note about the dress code--I read the OP as saying the boss is unwilling to provide a work environment where long sleeves and pants are reasonably comfortable, so this seems to go beyond a simple fashion preference.

Comment: Yes, OP noted that boss is strict about dress code, but this is an extraordinary situation and the boss may decide to go for it while the AC gets fixed. OP is *assuming* that boss will say no, when the answer is still not known.

Comment: @JohnSpiegel in that case one should proceed as suggested in the rest of my answer. You are right, it *could be* that OP's petition is denied, as well as it could be accepted.